# How do I restore my Google Cloud service to its initial state, I am trying to start again all the setup of Google Cloud like the beginning

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I create a virtual machine, it does not assign network and IPs. Before it did everything correctly. The problem is that I have been modifying things that I should not, so I prefer to restore my Google Cloud service to its original state of the first time I accessed it. I do not care if projects are deleted or anything else is restored to the initial parameters. How do I restore my Google Cloud service to its initial state

How do I restore my Google Cloud service to its initial state, I am trying to start again all the setup of Google Cloud like the beginning

Comment: You can't restore the default parameter. You can create a new project if you want. However, it's convenient at the beginning to have default parameters to start fast. Then, with experience, you can go over those parameters and understand deeper the services. If you don't have network and IPs, maybe you don't have VPC in your project. You have to create one, create also a subnet in the same region as your VM. If you need to access it, open the correct firewall rules,...

Answer (score 2):

To start over, create a new project.

[Creating and managing projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects)

Then delete the old project.

[Shutting down (deleting) projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects)

It takes 30 days for Google to delete a project. Typically, you will have a quota of five projects. That means while a project is in a deleted state, it will count against your total project quota.

Creating and deleting projects is a supported and recommended method of learning and testing. One additional benefit is that you will not be billed for resources that you create but forget to delete when you delete the entire project.

[Managing project quotas](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#managing_project_quotas)